# Get property of first table in a LEFT JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Consider the tables :

Worker
[image]

and WorkersBosses (Many to Many)

[image]

How can I get all the employees with their bosses (if a worker has a boss so put it besides him , else just put a null) .

With this :

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [EmployeeName] ,workboss.bossid
  FROM [TestingDB].[dbo].[Worker] as workers
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [TestingDB].[dbo].[WorkersBosses] as workboss
  on workers.EmployeeId = workboss.WorkerId
```

I get all the employees with their bosses , but how can I get also the boss' name (and not just his ID) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `INNER JOIN` to `Worker`:

```
SELECT
    w.EmployeeName AS EmployeeName,
    wb.BossName
FROM Worker w
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT b.WorkerId, b.BossId, w2.EmployeeName AS BossName
    FROM WorkersBoss b
    INNER JOIN Worker w2
        ON w2.EmployeeId = b.BossId 
)wb
    ON w.EmployeeId = wb.WorkerId
```

This can also be written as:

```
SELECT
    w.EmployeeName AS EmployeeName,
    w2.EmployeeName AS BossName
FROM Worker w
LEFT JOIN WorkersBosses wb
    INNER JOIN Worker w2
        ON w2.EmployeeId = wb.BossId
    ON w.EmployeeId = wb.WorkerId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the same table multiple times just by using a different alias:

```
SELECT w.EmployeeId,
    w.EmployeeName,
    b.EmployeeId AS BossEmployeeId,
    b.EmployeeName AS BossEmployeeName
FROM Worker w
LEFT JOIN WorkersBosses wb
    ON wb.WorkerId = w.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN Worker b
    ON b.EmployeeId = wb.BossId
```